# Zedgraph FillType.GradientByY solid

Tags: c#, winforms, zedgraph

I have a horizontal bar which I want to change colour when in range, which works, however the bar has a gradient and can see how to disable the gradient and change colour.

```
Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.Red, Color.Green }; 
BarItem myBar = pane1.AddBar("Null", list1Null, Color.Red);
myBar.Bar.Fill = new Fill(colors);
myBar.Bar.Fill.Type = FillType.GradientByY;
```

Has anyone achieved this please?

Answer (score 2):

GradientByY has this description - "Fill with a single solid color based on the Y value of the data."
[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wFpf.png)

However it has a gradient, by adding:

```
myBar.Bar.Fill.SecondaryValueGradientColor = Color.Empty;
```

It no longer has a gradient, just solid red or green, just what I wanted!

[Fixed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDR8K.png)
[Green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhthT.png)